# how to make overflow content hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using a video tag and applying zoom feature on it in REACTJS and I want to apply the feature to video that is being played inside it and not to the whole container. For that i am using `overflow:"hidden"` property but after applying this, whole container getting hide.

```
function=()=>{
    this.video.style.transform.scale=this.video.style.transform.scale+1
}

 <div style={{overflow:"hidden"}}>
      <video id="myVideo" style={{
            marginTop:"-40vw",
            marginBottom:0,
            marginLeft:"10vw",
            width:"30vw",
            height:"30vw",
            position:"fixed"
            src={this.state.source} /> 
 </div>
<button onClick={this.function}></button>
```

Comment: Can you consider using `position: absolute` and increasing the `z-index` of the video (not the container)? This way you can mask it on top of everything.

Comment: I am not so sure to understand the `marginTop: -40vw`, you tell the video to be placed -40% of the width of the viewport. You should use `vh` unit for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a little example starting from your code. Is this something like this you are searching for?

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hellman-3i6bf?file=/src/App.js

Also, your `overflow:hidden` on the container won't work correctly as its width and height are not defined. So it will keep growing as the video is scaling up.